# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of large sparse matrix in Python Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

My Python code generates upper triangle of a matrix in coordinate (COO) format (row,col,mat_element) and stores non-zero elements only to decrease memory usage. However, it is sparse symmetric matrix and I wish to obtain it's eigenvalues and eigenvectors using 'eigsh' from 'scipy.sparse.linalg'. How can I do this?

I would prefer to convert COO to CSR matrix directly and give it as an input for 'eigsh'. But if that is not possible I would like to make the matrix symmetric first and then convert it to CSR format.

COO and CSR matrix wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Comment: There is a scipy.sparse.linalg section with eig functions.  Read the docs.  You may have to expand the matrix to include lower triangular part.

Comment: Is there a simple way to do that using scipy sparse itself?

Comment: You can convert to CSR with [`tocsr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.tocsr.html), then add the matrix to its [`transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.transpose.htm) to get the full symmetric matrix that you can pass to [`eigsh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html).

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks! This seems to work but still partially... because in the process of adding the transpose, elements in the diagonal get doubled. To correct this, if I do 'mat_csr = mat_csr + mat_csr.getH() - mat_csr.diagonal()' it gives an entirely different and unexpected matrix.

Comment: @Aman_X `diagonal` does not give you the diagonal matrix, but the diagonal values as a vector, so adding or subtracting them will affect to every row (due to broadcasting). You can do `mat_csr = mat_csr + mat_csr.getH() - mat_csr * scipy.sparse.eye(*mat_csr.shape, dtype=mat_csr.dtype)`.

Comment: @jdehesa Ah ok! You have been very helpful. It is my lack of expertise in Python because of which I make mistakes. Anyway, I was able to modify my code to add transpose before creating diagonal elements. So it works now.